# Check if a user is signed in using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I do this? I don't care about their permission level, only if they are signed in or not.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best way to check is look for _spPageContextInfo.userId property which is available on pretty much all pages. I would think it will be not available or null when user is not logged in.

Comment: Your way is neat. +1

Answer (score 2):

If You are at SharePoint page and You are logged in than You can get User Id and User Name in browser console.

```
_spPageContextInfo.id

_spPageContextInfo.UserLoginName
```

**ID**: Returns user Id number Like 111,123 etc.

**LoginName**: returns Your Email Address.

If You are on Sharepoint page but not logged in

**ID**: returns `undefined`

**LoginName**: return `undefined`

You can Use `_SpPageContentInfo` in CSOM, HTMl String and sever object modal.